# Subscribing to an MvvmCross Service for Windows Phone 8 background tasks

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, service, background, mvvmcross

I'm working on the Windows Phone 8 part of an MvvmCross app.  I need to build it so that when the app is running in the background, it will periodically check a server for updates, and if there are any, display a toast notification.

Since the core of the project already has a service that checks for updates and publishes messages when it finds them, I was wondering if there was a way that I could subscribe to this service in App.xaml.cs and give it a method to handle anything published by the server communication service.

Is this even possible?  Are there any better ways to do this?  I realize that background running is very platform-specific, but are there any MvvmCross plugins that could help?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you would be able to implement this just as you would for a normal Windows Phone 8 background task.  I don't know of any plugins to do this as each platform handles this in their own way.... Take [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) as an example.  You need to modify the app manifest file and overwrite the DefaultTasks element in WMAppManifest.xml with something like:

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml">
  <BackgroundExecution>
    <ExecutionType  Name="MyBackgroundThing" />
  </BackgroundExecution>
</DefaultTask>
```

Then in App.xaml you need to overwrite the **shell:PhoneApplicationService** element to register an event handler for the RunningInBackgroundEvent, like so:

```
<shell:PhoneApplicationService 
    Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" 
    Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"
    RunningInBackground="Application_RunningInBackground"/>
```

Then in App.xaml.cs you need to declare some static variables that will be global to the application.  This probably includes a reference to your background service and a RunningInBackground bool.  Like so:

```
public static MyBackgroundService BackgroundService{ get; set; }
public static bool RunningInBackground { get; set; }
```

In App.xaml.cs, add the RunningInBackground event handler like so:

```
private void Application_RunningInBackground(object sender,    RunningInBackgroundEventArgs args)
{
    RunningInBackground = true;
    // Suspend all unnecessary processing such as UI updates
}
```

Also update the Application_activated method to set the RunningInBackground global variable back to false, like so:

```
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    RunningInBackground = false;
}
```

Depending on what else your service is doing their maybe other things to do but that should be the brunt of it...